# Change control using CVS

Tags: 7, version-control

We're looking to manage our install of Drupal 7 with CVS (sadly Git and SVN are out). Do you have any pointer for things to think about when setting up the repositories?

Our lay of the land is as follows:

- Our staff include UI developers, back-end developers , administrators, and DBAs.
- For starting, we're going to install various modules (e.g. Domain, LDAP, Workflow, and Views). We'll write some custom modules down the road. We're also looking for implementing our own look and feel.
- We have Dev, Test/QA, and Production instances of Drupal. The flow of code and configurations  will be from Dev to Test/QA to Production (with some looping between Dev and Test).
- We'll have top level domains and several subdomains.
- We're on RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.5, MySQL 5.x and Apache 2.x.

What are the ways of managing changes that have worked for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regardless the used VCS, here is what I put in my code repository

- A [`.make`](http://drupal.org/project/drush_make) file used to download Drupal core, contrib modules and contrib themes and apply patches (if required)
- a `module` folder with only the custom modules
- a `themes` folder with only the custom themes
- A build script to

  - run `drush make` on the `.make` file to download Drupal core and contribs to a (VCS ignored) `dist` folder
  - copy the `modules` folder to `dist/sites/all/modules/custom`
  - copy the `themes` folder to to `dist/sites/all/themes/custom`

This to

- properly track changes to the custom code
- properly track used core and contribs versions (in the `.make` file)
- prevent core or contribs hack
- allow proper patching (Drush Make requires the applied patches to be on publicly accessible)

For the build script, I use [Phing](http://www.phing.info/) but any scripting languages (ant, bash, php, ruby, etc.) could be used. With some additional work, the build script can also be used to run automated test ([SimpleTest](http://drupal.org/simpletest)) and code validation (`php -l` and [Coder Review](http://drupal.org/project/coder)).

I try to have as much configuration as possible exported into code. Mainly by using *exportables* through the Features module and by having a project specific profile to define and update non-exportable configurations through its [`hook_install`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) and [`hook_update_N`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) implementations. See [The Development -> Staging -> Production Workflow Problem in Drupal](http://developmentseed.org/blog/2009/jul/09/development-staging-production-workflow-problem-drupal) and the [Code driven development: using Features effectively in Drupal 6 and 7](http://www.archive.org/details/CodeDrivenDevelopmentUsingFeaturesEffectivelyInDrupal6And7) presentation.